# Log file permissions in Oracle WebLogic

Tags: linux, weblogic

I have changed the `startWeblogic.sh` script to give read access to the log files.

Here are examples:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall   81586 Apr 15 22:43 access.log    
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall  700087 Apr 15 22:45 localhost.log
-rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall   20553 Apr 15 22:49 localhost.out
```

From the above other users got read permissions for access.log and localhost.log, but its not assigning read access to localhost.out log file. Please suggest which configuration file to change.

Comment: Can you please tell what changes were made in startweblogic.sh

Comment: What did you change? What is the umask of the session that starts WebLogic, and is it set set/changed in any script you run?

Comment: i have set umask 022 in startweblogic.sh and after i can see the above permissions

Comment: But i am not getting read access to localhost.out for other users. Where to change the properties for localhost.out log file

Comment: Are you calling startWeblog.sh directly, or through your own wrapper script? I'm not sure what is creating that .out file; are you nohup'ing the server, perhaps?

Comment: we are starting the weblogic like   nohup sh startWebLogic.sh & but this creates nohup.out

Comment: For your info servers/DEV_Managed/logs/localhost.out :<Apr 9, 2015 11:56:30 AM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server output log file is '/u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/sdomain/servers/DEV_Managed/logs/localhost.out'

Comment: The above explains server output log file is localhost.out

Comment: Maybe you need to set the umask in `bin/nodemanager/wlscontrol.sh` as well then? If you can't set it in the shell you're starting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set umask 022 in startweblogic.sh and startnodemanager.sh and wlscontrol.sh worked